# WCF Data service is not accessible from remote server

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have service like this :

```
> http://108.109.95.29/winrtapp/THA001_devDataService.svc/
```

it gives me an error:

I host this services at windows server 2003 IIS, when I call the same service from localhost it is working fine.

i am accessing this service in [windows metro application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/) app

Error is :

[image]

`

Comment: what security have u implemented on the wcf service? this exception is 500 error, i.e refuse to access.it means that ur app need some kind of permission to access it.

Comment: so you mean that i hosted web service perfectly, the problem is in my application access?

Comment: the hosted service seems okay to me since i can ping it from here it means its on public ip and any remote device should be able to access it. Can u share ur congif xml file, i mean the security part?

Comment: where i can find congif xml? please

Comment: hey saw ur code. u r trying to hit an 'https' this wont work until and unless u have certificates installed on ur remote device. Check my answer section. i will get a abort error. the code is 500 for abort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error while accessing https. As i dont have the necessary certificates installed on my machine so i wont be able to access it.

Similarly ur windows phone dont have the certificates in it. thats y its giving that error

[image: error]

I had faced similar kind of situation while i was making an wcf service for azure.

[See if this helps you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520736/call-a-https-wcf-service-with-certificate-authentication)

Check the code in the controller i had to write for my mvc application. I had to giv the path of the certificate in order to authenticate my https.

similarly have will u have to write code for ur windows phone to authenticate the https request.