# Obtaining valid certificates from browser cert store for signing purposes

Tags: c#, linq

I need to create a simple signing client in WPF. The workstation has already been configureed with a set of certificates imported by a smart card. One of them is the signing certificate, others are used for email authentication and encryption.

So I am making a simple drop down list where the user can select his preferred certificate from the list, but I would like to exclude certificates not related to signing of documents. By examining the certificate I can read its purpose, then I would like to read it programmagically.

So far I wrote:

```
        IEnumerable<Certificate> certificates;

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        try
        {
            certificates = from X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates
                           where certificate.HasPrivateKey
                           && certificate.NotAfter <= DateTime.Now && certificate.NotBefore >= DateTime.Now
                           select new Certificate
                           {
                               CommonName = certificate.SubjectName.Decode(X500DistinguishedNameFlags.UseUTF8Encoding),
                               Id = Convert.ToString(certificate.GetSerialNumber())
                           };
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
```

The result of the above code is a list that at least includes a well known email authentication certificate.

What is the condition to add in order to check that the certificate has `usage attribute == non repudiation`?

Comment: You possibly could look at the `Extensions` collection and search for the `KeyUsage` extension https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keyusageextension(v=vs.110).aspx. There is the `KeyUsages` property that should tell you what kind of certificate you actually examine. I would put that in an answer but I am not sure this is what you need.

Comment: You could have posted the answer, in fact thanks to you I found **the** correct solution

Comment: this might help   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17520736/call-a-https-wcf-service-with-certificate-authentication

Comment: @NewtonSheikh no. That is a different topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key part of the answer, accepted by the OP is:

You possibly could look at the `Extensions` collection and search for the `KeyUsage` extension.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keyusageextension(v=vs.110).aspx

There is the `KeyUsages` property that should tell you what kind of certificate you actually examine.

Answer (score 0):

Kudos to @WiktorZychla

```
        IEnumerable<Certificate> certificates;

        X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        try
        {
            certificates = from X509Certificate2 certificate in store.Certificates
                           where certificate.HasPrivateKey
                               //&& certificate.NotAfter <= DateTime.Now && certificate.NotBefore >= DateTime.Now
                           //Commented because doesn't work, strangely
                           && certificate.Extensions.OfType<X509KeyUsageExtension>().Any(ku => ku.KeyUsages == X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation)
                           select new Certificate
                           {
                               CommonName = certificate.SubjectName.Decode(X500DistinguishedNameFlags.UseUTF8Encoding),
                               Id = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(certificate.GetSerialNumber())
                           };
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }
```